# Random paste in my Outlook object with a CopyPicture

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm running everyday a script who send an email to many people, but i have a random issue on this script, there is two differents ways.

**First** : The picture is correctly pasted in my outlook object, so everything works fine.

**Second** : The picture is pasted in Excel and not Outlook, and the script is locked here, without error from the application.

That's really disturbing because when it's me i relaunch and it's all ok, but if someone else want to do the manipulation and the bug appears, that's not good.

I use CopyPicture and SendKeys "^v" to paste it in Outlook.

**Here is my code :**

```
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
If colonne = 10 Then
Range("A1:AA103").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Else
Range("A1:AA97").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
End If
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
            .To = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ""
            .HTMLBody = ""

  .display

End With
SendKeys "^v"
```

There is a HTMLBody and a Subject, but that's only text so i only put the important code here.

I already looked every solution given before, but none respond to my random issue.

Thank you

Comment: I think the reason is that message window is not visible when you are triggering  `Sendkeys` action. Try to add 2-3 seconds waiting time just before that line.

Comment: Hello Jawor, yes i tried this before asking the question, i placed it after the .display, and after the End With too. That change nothing I have the same problem. Sometimes, the outlook is already open but the paste don't work

Comment: Never rely on `SendKeys` for anything. It is unreliable.

Comment: Hi @braX , yeah maybe this solution it's a little bit old ^^ What do you recommend to me ? I'm on Outlook 2010

Answer (score -1):

Try using DoEvents after display

```
.Display
DoEvents
```